# How to do drag and drop like medium?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, draftjs

I am new to javascript I am pretty confused with this drag n drop operation .I wanted to like medium.com 
Like this.

GIF
[image]

I am building an content Editor with draft js , And 
I don't have any idea how to do this in javascript.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more what you are looking for? Do you just want an explanation of html 5 drag and drop?

Comment: NO i want the funtionality like .When i Drag the Image it automatically suggest the location Right I want Like that

Comment: So you want it work such that as you are entering the drop area, the area expands with a border indicating that this is where the data will be shown?

Comment: Yup That's Right .. Could you pls help with that

Comment: There are libraries that do that....

Comment: I want this in pure JavaScript because  I wanted to Learn these things And Implement in my Content Editor @epascarello

Comment: Than look for tutorials on drag and drop....

Comment: No I've Searched For it there no tutorial have taught this type of drap n drop mechanism.. @epascarello

Comment: You can look at the example in my answer or you can look at this tutorial https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Which is where I learned html drag and drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dragEnter as an event to add css to the area. There are a lot of ways to do it.

```
<div ondragenter="dragEnter()" class="div1" id="test" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

And then in the js

```
function dragEnter(e){
var thing = document.getElementById('test');
thing.classList.add('div2');

}
```

your css would look like this

```
.div1 {
width: 350px;
 height: 70px;
padding: 10px;

  }
.div2 {
 width: 350px;
 height: 70px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
 }
```

Here is a jsfiddle example.
http://jsfiddle.net/camccar/afPrc/197/

Comment: Question Close saying too. Broad. It wasnt